# Get count of two different values but not same values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table format.

```
  **ID     Name     Start Date    End Date**   
    1      ABC      1/1/2015     12/31/2015
    1      XYZ      4/1/2015     8/31//2015
    1      DEF      1/1/2012     12/31/2012
    2      ABC      1/23/2011     1/23/2012
    2      ABC      1/31/2012     1/31/2013
    3      DEF      2/12/2015     5/30/2015
    3      XYZ      4/1/2015      6/01/2015
    4      DEF      3/1/2015      12/31/2015
    4      DEF      4/1/2015      6/30/2015
```

I need the count of ID's having Different Name which lies in date range of May 2015

Expected Results

```
ID   COUNT
1      2   
3      2
```

P.S - ID 4 also lies in the date range of MAY 2015, but the Name is same i.e DEF. So I need only ID's 1 and 3 but not 4.

Thank You in advance and appreciated for your efforts.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service,  where you post your requirements and we crank out code or SQL to meet them. We're happy to help solve a problem when you've made an effort to do so yourself first. What have you attempted so far that isn't working for you?

Comment: ID 3 doesn't have both rows overlapping that month -- why should it be returned?

Comment: @Ken White - I tried for hours using Count syntax with regular Group By and Having BY statement. I had given up as I couldn't get exact logic for the expected results and so I approached StackOverflow which was a lifesaver for me many times earlier. ..: :)

Comment: @sgeddes  -- My bad. I updated the table.ID 3 now lies in the May date range.

Comment: If you *tried for hours*, you should be able to at least post one of your efforts. Without it, it's like the student saying *Honest, teacher! I did my homework! My dog ate it!*. If SO has been a lifesaver for you many times now, you should know how to ask a question (and should have more than 6 reputation points), especially having been a member here for more than a year.

Comment: as per your description and desired result, entry 3      XYZ      4/1/2015      6/01/2015 also not consider in output as per your logic for id=4. So I think out put will be "
first row - 1      2    second row -
3      1" is it right, confirm it?

Comment: @Ajay2707 Nope. Basically I need all the ID's  which has overlapping date ranges (Of different Names). ID 3 indeed exists because it is in the date range of May for both (XYZ,DEF). ID 4 shouldn't be included because though its in the May Date range , it has the same Name...

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your sample data doesn't match your desired results, but I think this is what you're looking for using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select id, count(*)
from yourtable
group by id
having sum(case when '5/1/2015' between startdate and enddate then 1 else 0 end) > 1
   and count(distinct name) = count(name)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6284/3)

The `sum` aggregation in the `having` clause is making sure there are multiple records in between that date.  The `count` clause in the `having` clause is making sure there aren't any duplicates.

Comment: Yipeee. I am almost close to the results I want. I am testing your query with my real time data. Thank You @sgeddes for your quick response.

Comment: Query is partially right, but not working to the exact results, I think its breaking reagrding DISTINCT Count(name) in HAVING clause. It's taking the count even though ID is not in the date range.I have re edited the Query table having one more ID with 1 (But date range is not in the range)

Comment: @user3594484 -- not sure I'm completely understanding your comment, but if it's counting records outside of the range, perhaps you need to add `where` criteria to filter on only those records.

Comment: @user3594484 -- perhaps you mean it's returning the correct ids with the wrong count?  If so, replace the `count(*)` with the `sum` clause in the `having` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
  @startdate datetime = '20150501',
  @enddate datetime = '20150531'

select t.id, count(distinct t.name)
from mytable t
where t.startdate <= @enddate and t.enddate >= @startdate
group by t.id
having count(distinct t.name) > 1
```